# How to use an inline java comparator in a jsp file?

Tags: java, html, jsp, comparator

I have to use a Java Inline comparator in a JSP file to sort the my html drop down as per date wise. 
My code is

```
<%if(cpRecordForm.getIArray() != null && cpRecordForm.getIArray().length >0){ 
    for(int i=1;i<cpRecordForm.getIArray().length;i++){
        if(cpRecordForm.getIArray()[i].getCaNum() != null){
            if(!caseNum.contains(cpRecordForm.getIArray()[i].getCaNum())){
                caseNum.add(cpRecordForm.getIArray()[i].getCaNum());
                date = dateFormat.parse(((Insp)(cpRecordForm.getIArray()[i])).getDate()); 
                dateFormat.format(date);%>
                    <html:option
                        value='<%=""+((Insp)(cpRecordForm.getIArray()[i])).getCaNum()%>'>
                        <%=((Insp)(cpRecordForm.getIArray()[i])).getCaNum()%>
                    </html:option>
<%}}}}%>
```

In code I need to use an inline comparator to sort the `getCaNum` from `date`. Date is the attribute of `getIArray()[i]`.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: ugh. That should all be done in Java, then the resulting sorted list made available to the jsp with something like `req.setAttribute("options", sortedList);` which can loop on `<c:forEach items="${options}"...>` and output the `<html:option value='...'>` at that point with `req.setAttribute("options", sortedList);`